# Using c++ enum in QML as string

Tags: c++, qt, enums, qml, qtquick2

What I would like to do is use the below enum in c++:

```
class MyClass : public QQuickItem {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(MyEnum enumValue READ getEnumValue)

public:
    enum MyEnum{
        MyEnumElement = 0
    };
    Q_ENUM(MyEnum)

slots:
    MyEnum getEnumValue(){
        return enumValue;
    }

private: 
    MyEnum enumValue = MyEnumElement;
};
```

In such a way in QML:

```
MyClass {
    id: myClass
}

Text {
    text: "enumValue is: " + myClass.enumValue
}
```

That would result in `enumValue is MyEnumElement` instead of `enumValue is 0` which is the case now. The solution I have now is the following, however inelegant:

```
class MyClass : public QQuickItem {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(MyEnum enumValue READ getEnumValue)

public:
    enum MyEnum{
        MyEnumElement = 0
    };
    Q_ENUM(MyEnum)
    QMetaEnum MyEnum_MetaEnum = QMetaEnum::fromType<MyEnum>();
    Q_INVOKABLE QString getEnumString(MyEnum enumVal){
        return MyEnum_MetaEnum.valueToKey(enumVal);
    }

slots:
    MyEnum getEnumValue(){
        return enumValue;
    }

private: 
    MyEnum enumValue = MyEnumElement;
};
```

And:

```
MyClass {
    id: myClass
}

Text {
    text: "enumValue is: " + myClass.getEnumString(myClass.enumValue)
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 7):

I found the following to work:

```
class MyClass : public QQuickItem {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QVariant enumValue READ getEnumValue)

public:
    enum MyEnum{
        MyEnumElement = 0
    };
    Q_ENUM(MyEnum)

slots:
    QVariant getEnumValue(){
        return QVariant::fromValue(enumValue);
    }

private: 
    MyEnum enumValue = MyEnumElement;
};
```

QML side:

```
MyClass {
    id: myClass
}

Text {
    text: "enumValue is: " + myClass.enumValue.toString()
}
```

Using without `.toString()` still causes the `QVariant` to be cast to an int. I'm still open to more elegant solutions.

**Edit:**

As expected, this breaks `switch` and `===` on the QML/Javascript side. `switch(enumValue.valueOf())` and `==` must be used when comparing to enum ints exported by `Q_ENUM()`, such as `MyClass.MyEnumElement`:

```
switch(myClass.enumValue.valueOf()){
    case MyClass.MyEnumElement:
        ...
        break;
}
```

and

```
if(myClass.enumValue == MyClass.MyEnumElement)
    ...
```