# qml list view to print text values from enum

Tags: c++, enums, qml

How to display a text representation of an enum value for ListView in QML?

I have the following working example which is able to print the enum value as number. But I can't find a solution how to print some text in the ListView. For example I want to see "Thats three" if enum value THREE.

Sorry for the long code, but I can't reduce it as that is the "minimum"...

MyListModel.h:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QAbstractListModel>

#include <iostream>

enum SomeEnum
{
    ONE,
    TWO,
    THREE
};

struct MyListItem
{
    QString heading;
    QString description;
    int quantity;
    SomeEnum someEnum;
};


Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(SomeEnum)

class MyListModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_ENUMS(MyRoles)
public:
    enum MyRoles {
        HeadingRole = Qt::UserRole + 1,
        DescriptionRole,
        QuantityRole,
        EnumRole
    };

    using QAbstractListModel::QAbstractListModel;

    QHash<int,QByteArray> roleNames() const override {
        return { { HeadingRole, "heading" },
            { DescriptionRole, "description" },
            { QuantityRole, "quantity" },
            { EnumRole, "someEnum" }    // Der erste Text EnumRole entspricht dem EnumValue aus MyRoles, someEnum ist aus Qml model.someEnum
        };
    }
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex()) const override {
        if (parent.isValid())
            return 0;
        return m_list.size();
    }

    bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role) override
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;

        if (!hasIndex(index.row(), index.column(), index.parent()) || !value.isValid())
            return false;

        MyListItem &item = m_list[index.row()];
        if (role == DescriptionRole) item.description = value.toString();
        else if (role == HeadingRole) item.heading = value.toString();
        else if (role == QuantityRole) item.quantity = value.toInt();
        else if (role == EnumRole ) item.someEnum = value.value<SomeEnum>();
        else return false;

        emit dataChanged(index, index, { role } );

        return true ;

    }


    QVariant data(const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override {
        std::cout << "Asking for data" << index.row() << " " << role << std::endl;

        if (!hasIndex(index.row(), index.column(), index.parent()))
            return {}; 

        const MyListItem &item = m_list.at(index.row());
        if (role == DescriptionRole) return item.description; 
        if (role == HeadingRole) return item.heading;
        if (role == QuantityRole) return item.quantity;
        if (role == EnumRole ) return item.someEnum;

        return {}; 
    }



private:
    QVector<MyListItem> m_list = {
        { "heading 1", "description 1", 1, ONE },
        { "heading 2", "description 2", 42, TWO },
        { "heading 3", "description 3", 4711, THREE }
    };
};
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

#include "MyListModel.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView view;

    qmlRegisterType<MyListModel>("MyTypes", 1, 0, "ExportedListModel"); 

    MyListModel mymodel;
    view.engine()->rootContext()->setContextProperty("mymodel", &mymodel); 

    view.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("MyItem.qml"));
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

MyItem.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import MyTypes 1.0

ListView {
    id: listView
    anchors.fill: parent

    delegate: Item {
        implicitHeight: text.height
        //width: listView.width + 500
        width: 1000
        Text {
            id: text
            text: model.heading + " " + model.description + " " + model.quantity + " " + model.someEnum
        }

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: text
            onClicked: {
                model.quantity *= 2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your code misses the `data(...)` implementation in `MyListModel`?

Comment: @Amfasis: lost by copy & paste. Now it is in. Thanks!

Comment: @Klaus: Maybe the following post might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37663286/5762796

Comment: I'm not sure what you like to achieve, If you want the ListView to have a row for each of the enum values (in `MyListModel`) you should set `model: ExportedListModel { id: model1 }` (or was this also lost in copy paste ;-) ? )

Comment: @Amfasis: Don't understand your question. I have one column which has an enum value as content. I want to print a text depending on the enum value and not the number there. I did not know what ExportedListModel is.

Comment: `ExportedListModel` is what you tell qmlRegisterType in your main function. I don't get how the ListView is important here