# qml: How to format column of a listview

Tags: qt, listview, qml

I have a list view but all text elements start printing at x position 0.
Is it possible to format the column width? I can set the text element x position by simply

```
x: 100
```

But that seems to be the wrong way. How can I set the row width to see the content like a table?

What I currently have prints all elements in the first row.

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import MyTypes 1.0

ListView {
    id: listView
    implicitWidth: contentItem.childrenRect.width

    anchors.fill: parent
    //model: mymodel  
    model: ExportedListModel {} 

    delegate: Item {
        implicitHeight: text1.height
        TextEdit {
            id: text1
            text: model.heading 
            Keys.onReturnPressed: model.heading = text
        }   

        TextEdit {
            id: text2
            text: model.description
            Keys.onReturnPressed: model.description = text
        }

        TextEdit {
            id: text3
            text: model.quantity
            Keys.onReturnPressed: model.quantity = text
        }

        TextEdit {
            id: text4
            text: model.someEnum
            Keys.onReturnPressed: model.someEnum = text
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should specify the width property in your List View and not the implicitWidth. The latter is just a hint.

Besides, what is referenced by your "contentItem" ?

You can specify your delegate's item width as it is done in the second example here : 
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html

EDIT : 
Whether it is "width" or "implicitWidth" properties, the example will work.
To use the column, it is important to provide a sufficient height value to your delegate's root item in order to be able to display all the rows in your column.

Here is a working example inspired by yours, you can copy paste it in an empty QtQuick project :

import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ListModel {
        id: mymodel
        ListElement {
            TEXT: "text_1"
            ID: 1
            COMMENT: "Comment1"
        }
        ListElement {
            TEXT: "text_2"
            ID: 2
            COMMENT: "Comment2"
        }
        ListElement {
            TEXT: "text_3"
            ID: 3
            COMMENT: "Comment3"
        }
        ListElement {
            TEXT: "text_4"
            ID: 4
            COMMENT: "Comment4"
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id: listView
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: mymodel

        delegate:
            Rectangle
        {
            implicitWidth: contentItem.childrenRect.width
            implicitHeight: textEdit.height*2
            border.color: "black"
            border.width: 1
            color: "red"


            Column{
                TextEdit {
                    id: textEdit
                    color: "white"
                    text: TEXT + " number is " + ID
                }

                TextEdit {
                    id: textEdit2
                    color: "white"
                    text: COMMENT
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Here is a picture of the result :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/30Qak.jpg

Comment: "Second Example" Sorry, I can only see something like "width: 200". But I want format the whole column. How can I set the width of the column in a list view? I want all text elements in the same column have the same width. If I set "width: 100 " to all my Text items nothing changes. Is it possible to get working example code?

Comment: I have edited the answer. Put a column in your delegate Item. Let me know if this works.

Comment: I added your code to my one. Still all is printed in first row.

Comment: Can you specify what is inside ExportedListModel {}  ?

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57144486/qml-list-view-to-print-text-values-from-enum?noredirect=1#comment100808797_57144486

Comment: Gotcha a better example